# C# Events at same time ignored

Tags: c#, event-handling, event-log

I am currently running into a problem with an eventlog monitor I created a while ago.

My application subscribes to the EntryWritten events of the EventLog.
I noticed that if multiple events occurs at the same time (within the same second), only one of them raises the event which triggers my eventhandler.

```
_eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog(_logName);
_eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(eventlog_EntryWritten);
_eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Is it possible to avoid this behavior, so my eventlog_EntryWritten method will be called for all events that are logged to the eventlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events usually dont run in Async mode, and so if eventlog_EntryWritten does not finish before another event, you probably miss the events. Raise your own async event in fire and forget method. I am not sure, but probably this will be more effective. Or have your own class using polling mechanism to read the events.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I'll try to utilize .NET 4's task factory to do this.

Comment: So far it seems to work using this approach. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

It's worse than that - it's within a five second interval:

> The system responds to WriteEntry only if the last write event occurred at least five seconds previously. This implies you will only receive one EntryWritten event notification within a five-second interval, even if more than one event log change occurs.

(from [EventLog.EntryWritten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

If you need to track all events then (if they're yours), I'd suggest adding a wrapper function around WriteEntry that can catch all of the entries before they're even written to the log.

Comment: +1 for that last suggestion. Don't use events when you don't need to.

Comment: I found that as well, but it seems not to be the case. They are not my events. I found an example where two events have occured within 4 seconds and both have triggered by event handler.

Comment: @klugs: Is that 4 sec the difference between when they happened or when they were written? Anyway, EntryWritten  seems to be defined for another purpose than you want it for. Start working around.