# Memory Usage of EventLog Enumerator in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, event-log

Let's say that I have a long-running thread (A daemon or a service) and I don't want to unnecessarily accumulate memory, and I want to use the EventLog.

I have code similar to:

```
EventLog myEventLog = new EventLog;
myEventLog.Log = "Application";
IEnumerator eventEnumerator = myEventLog.Entries.GetEnumerator();
int eventLogIndex = 0;
```

Then I set up a method to go off at intervals to read from the EventLog:

```
while(myEventLog.Entries.Count > eventLogIndex)
{
    eventEnumerator.MoveNext();
    eventLogIndex ++;
    // do something with eventEnumerator.Current)
}
```

So the enumerator keeps moving up the eventlog if more stuff is added to it. I did it this way because I read  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816642/c-sharp-events-at-same-time-ignored) that using the EventWritten handler can miss events if the events come in at the same time.

My question is: Would this cause memory usage to accumulate?  Would used values of the eventlog be dropped from memory, or would the entire list of events stay in memory until the thread closes?  And, if so, is there a way around this that would be thread-safe regarding incoming EventLogEntries?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That depends on the implementation of the enumerator.  It has to go out of its way to check for updates and invalidate itself if there have been any.  Many iterators don't do this.

Comment: Even if the entries read are dropped (out of scope and no longer referenced), they will still consume memory until the garbage collector is executed, which might not happen any time soon. Just for debugging, you can run the garbage collector to find out if the memory shrinks.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch It is definitely not a case with EventLog. It's enumerator's implementation lazily loads each item from actual Windows log inside MoveNext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/EventLogInternal.cs) you can verify that **yes**, there is memory usage accumulation. And the usage will grow so long as you're holding a reference to EventLog instance.

However, what is accumulated is not instances of EventLogEntry class, but a raw log data. So the memory consumption would be **relatively** low.

You should check it in a real life scenarios, by simulating a typical behavior of your production system and tracking the memory usage.

Comment: I think I found some useful information in [MSDN's specification for the EventLog.Close() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.clear(v=vs.110).aspx):

Under remarks, it says that the EventLog's size is limited, and when it gets full, it either stops recording, or overwrites existing entries.  The Close() method is used to reset that.